# SignalR ASP.NET Core "Current" version

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Ref URL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Supported Platform for ASP.NET Core SignalR mentions "Current". I understand it means the latest. But wanted to ensure if this was used ONLY because browsers auto update themselves to the latest version ? Or Is there some other meaning to it ?

Comment: The best way to get an answer to that might be to use the built-in feedback system on the docs page itself.

Comment: Current means  Latest Version of these browsers. Let say it `71.0.3578.98` for google chrome.